# Is there a way to make offset higher by 10pixels?

Tags: jquery

I would like the scroll to be a bit more on the top. my content is centered. So when I scroll to it cuts off. is there a way to make the offset top be higher?

```
 $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#funnel-1-mobile").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if you want to offset by further `100px` than your current scroll position of the defined id, you shall use

```
 $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#funnel-1-mobile").offset().top -100
}, 1000);
```

Comment: @Dayan Cabrera, I'm glad to know that the example helps. Welcome.

Comment: @Dayan Cabrera, I don't know who down voted you. If others have the perception that you shall be as expert as they are it's wrong. I don't see anything in your question that deserves a down vote. I have my up vote for your question. You came here to learn and to be enlightened.